# No test is available in <path>\PKGS\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, jenkins

I am using .NET framework 4.5 and C# for my project and i used mstest for Test project. All unit test cases ran fine on Visual Studio 2017 enterprise edition, but when I created Jenkins for the Unit test, some of tests are executed and in middle the build fails saying:

> No test is available in
>   \PKGS\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll.
>   Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform
>   & framework version settings are appropriate and try again 
>   Additionally, path to test adapters can be specified using
>   /TestAdapterPath command. Example 
>   /TestAdapterPath:.   vstest.console.exe
>   F:\jnks\workspace\mPrint_Roam_Horizon_Inc\PKGS\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll
>   /InIsolation /EnableCodeCoverage

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the file Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll does not contain any tests (which is correct, because it is a frameworkfile). You probably have some errors in the path where you are looking for dll's with tests in them.

Comment: Yes ,agreed . I have ignored Microsoft dlls in the .runsettings .only for this dll there is error , rest all dlls are been ignored